# Why is this Groupby transform not working?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

For a dummy dataset, which each id corresponds to one match:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'score', 'duration', 'user'],
                  data=[[1, 800, 60, 'abc'], [1, 900, 60, 'zxc'], [2, 800, 250, 'abc'], [2, 5000, 250, 'bvc'],
                        [3, 6000, 250, 'zxc'], [3, 8000, 250, 'klp'], [4, 1400, 500,'kod'],
                        [4, 8000, 500, 'bvc']])
```

If I want to keep only the records where either one of the same id have duration greater than 120 and score greater than 1500, this works fine:

```
cond = df2['duration'].gt(120) & df2['score'].gt(1500)
out = df2[cond.groupby(df2['id']).transform('all')]
```

and returns 2 instances of the same id. However, if I want to keep only the pairs of id's where the user is 'abc' it does not work. I have tried:

```
out = df2[(df2['user'].eq('abc')).groupby(df2['id']).transform('all')]
out = df2[(df2['user'] == 'abc').groupby(df2['id']).transform('all')]
```

and they both return blank df's. How to solve this problem? The outcome should be any match that user 'abc' played in.

Comment: You don't appear to have any `id` groups which have `all` values equal to `abc` Maybe you meant `any`?

Comment: You want `'any'`, not  `'all'`.  " where either one of the same id " = "at least one" = "any"

Comment: thank you both, now I get it :) post it as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer

Comment: @idontknowmuch [done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69946373/17242583)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, you want `'any'`, not `'all'`:

```
out = df2[(df2['user'] == 'abc').groupby(df2['id']).transform('any')]
```